# Exponentiation of a vector

Tags: r, vector, exponentiation

Why is this true:

```
1:5 ^ 2
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

In my mind, it should be this:

```
1:5 ^ 2
#> [1]    1    4   27  256 3125
```

I tired looking up youtube videos to get an explanation or just googling exponentiation in R but I can't find it. I think it might have something to do with order of operations but it's been a long time since I've covered that topic.

Comment: Try `(1:5) ^ 2`, `^` takes precedence over the sequence `:`, so `1:5 ^ 2` is evaluated as `1:25`. Don't know why anything `^ 2` should be `(1:5) ^ (1:5)` though :)

Comment: See [`?Syntax`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) to the order of operations, noting that `^` (exponentiation) is _before_ `:` (sequencing).

Comment: Could someone please post a combination of these comments as an answer?